# Tomato virus attack

Tags: tomatoes, fruit-drop

My tomatoes seem to have a virus causing leaves to die and stems to turn dark brown and some tomatoes blackish but I still have tomatoes on the higher branches that look unaffected at the moment.
  Are they safe to eat?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would you please post a picture of your sick-looking plant so we can see what's going on? We could use more details too. Where do you live? Have you checked for insects or larvae? Is it just on one plant? Have there been any recent changes to weather or soil? You can just press the gray edit word and add the new information into your questions. Since you're new here, a look around our [help] will help you learn about the site. Let us know if you need help doing anything. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

No, just because a tomato doesn't show signs of a pathogen, doesn't mean it is safe to eat. You need to get to the root of the problem first.  I would highly recommend you first remove all the bad tomatoes from the plant and toss them. Go here: [tomato help](http://www.tomatodirt.com/tomato-diseases.html) This may help in diagnosing your disease.  If it's a fungus follow my next point. Second, go get some fertilizer with fungal killer.  It's not necessarily a virus affecting your tomatoes.  Treat the tomatoes with that and see if they perk up and look normal again. Just follow the recommendations on the package.  If it is another kind of pathogen, follow the instructions on the website.  Don't risk your own health on something that may cause you to get sick.